# What is the usage of guard let self = self else { return }

Tags: swift, self, guard, resulttype

I just learned how to use the Result type recently from [Sean Allen's video](https://youtu.be/8aPjqLqUEKA?t=626), and I get the idea of using it. However, while I was writing a code, there is a line I don't understand.

The line is 87 in the picture (or this -> `guard let self = self else { return }` )
At first, I was just doing the same stuff as he did, but I wonder why he add the line in the code. I think he wrote it because the self can be nil and wanted to make sure if the self is not nil and return from the function if it gets nil.

And my question is

1. when or in which situation the self can be nil?
   and
2. if self gets nil, I think it won't trigger the following line (the one for checking the result), so both of the updateUI function and presentGFAlert... function won't be triggered and nothing shows up on the screen, right?

[image]

Comment: Look at the line `NetworkManager.shared.getFollowers`, it uses `[weak self]`.  This means that the closure is not is not holding a reference to `self`, so you need to check if `self` is still assigned or has become `nil`.  This allows the "parent" object to be dereferenced while `getFollowers` is still been executed, but guards against it (ie attempting to reference `self` while it's `nil`) and allowing the parent object to go out of scope before the closure is called

Comment: 1) self can be nil if it is deallocated. 2) the result closure will still be triggered as ur `NetworkManager` is a singleton which will still exist even after self has been deallocated.

Comment: A real case example: You present that view controller as a modal, and want to use a Web API. You have slow connection, and decide to dismiss the controller before you get response. The closure will be called after, so when that ViewController (self here) might have been deallocated. Prevent that memory leak with a `[weak self]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concern is correct. Because `getFollowers` is an async task, user could go back to previous screen while the task is running. In that case, `self` could be `nil` and the `return` is okay.

On the other hand, to make sure there's no problem with completion block of `getFollowers` task, `self` will be captured as `strong` reference, that could cause memory leak even if user already leave that screen.
He uses `weak self` to prevent that happens.

Comment: Thank you for the response! So, what you are saying is since getFollowers takes some time (async task) and not really sure if the user is still in the view (or view controller?) for geting followers, I have to make sure if the self still points at the object which has a getFollowers function or not. 
If, as you mentioned, the user has gone back or gone to a different screen, I don't need the success or failure response for getFollowers, so that is why I can simply return and get out of getFollowers function?
Sorry please correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: true, it's actually related to Capturing Values of completion `closure`, please take a look at this doc.
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html

Answer (score 2):

Its because the closure defines its reference to `self` as being weak, this means if `self` is released, the block closure will not prevent self from being destructed, getting a reference count of 0. You can deal with this in the code in the closure, by using all references to self as self?, but this mean self could became `nil` mid way being executed, by using `guard let self = self else { return }`, you are saying if execution gets here, I want a strong reference to it, so the object will continue being available until the execution of the of the closure complete, basically all or nothing. This in the past could only happen with multi threaded apps, but with apples new async thread model making cooperative threads more common this is potential more possible.

Comment: Actually changing the reference count is atomic, so if an object is attempt to be used mid change, it could create a problem. but if its not atomic how can you get a strong reference to self atomically?